# Not able to create corner stroke line in android drawable file

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Can someone help? How can I create the outline given below in Android?

[image: corner stroke line]

I have tried but can't able to implement this background drawable. I have tried using `<layer-list>` and inside 4 `<item>` tags with the use of padding of the rectangle shape.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.